# Render json response from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in web services applications which already exist.I am getting below response and saving response in result in controller.I need to show this as table format like,Status Code,Parameters, and response.How to bring json response to view as table in rails?

> "{\"statusCode\":200,\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"Device.Description\",\"value\":\"Gateway Device\",\"dataType\":0,\"parameterCount\":1,\"message\":\"Success\"}]}"

```
   respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => result }
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of better options using js libraries, but if you want to just use jquery, you should create the table using plain HTML (giving an id to the tbody). Then use js to create a string and concatenate it with every attribute you need, for instance:

```
var tr = '<tr><td>';
tr += jsonResponse.firstAttribute;
tr += '</td><td>';
tr += jsonResponse.secondAttribute;
tr += '</td>';
...
$('#you-table-body-id').append(tr);
```

by doing so you will concatenate this chunk of html containing the data you want to exhibit in your site.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The response you are saving in controller is in string format. To render it as JSON,You first need to parse it to JSON as following:

```
JSON.parse("{\"statusCode\":200,\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"Device.Description\",\"value\":\"Gateway Device\",\"dataType\":0,\"parameterCount\":1,\"message\":\"Success\"}]}")
```

This will change it to:

```
{"statusCode"=>200, "parameters"=>[{"name"=>"Device.Description", "value"=>"Gateway Device", "dataType"=>0, "parameterCount"=>1, "message"=>"Success"}]}
```

You can render is as json:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: JSON.parse(result) }
end
```

Comment: ok Thanks.Now displaying response  in text area.I need to change as table format like status code ,Parameters.How to bring this as html table format?

Comment: You are using javascript to call this JSON returning action?

Comment: Appending in response in textarea in java script -        $('#http_response').append("Parameter Name : "+result["response"].parameter_name+"\n\nResponse Time : " + result["response"].response_time + " sec\n\nResponse Body : \n" + pretty);

Comment: To show that in a table you would need to create html table with columns(parameter, statecode etc. with html ids)  and then assign them data like each column

Comment: Sure. Please upvote or mark if it helps you. Thanks!

Comment: i have create table but data is not displaying

Comment: <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="http_response" class="table table-bordred table-bordred table-striped">
            <thead>
              <th>Response</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Mac</td>
                <td>Parameter Name</td>
                <td>Response</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>

Comment: var tr;
          tr = $('<tr>');
          tr.append("<td>" + mac + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + result["response"].parameter_name + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + result["response"].response_time + "</td>");
          $('#http_response').first().append(tr);

Comment: getting value now.But it is not placing in table.It is just printing data in ui.